127.0.0.1 refused to connect ERROR when accessing a link
I'm using Laravel 11 and the latest bootstrap version to create a button and also Google Project Idx as my code editor. I got 127.0.0.1 error message when I click the button which is linking to a route as follows:
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="{{ route('iku.create') }}" role="button">Tambah IKU</a>

when I hover the button it shows the url "127.0.0.1:9002/iku/create". It shows correct route/folder & file but the server port is 9002 instead of the default port which is 8000. I don't know if this is the problem.
this is my Controller code:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Iku;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class ikucontroller extends Controller
{

    public function create() : View {
            return view('iku.create');
        }
}

and this is inside the Routing web.php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


//route resource for iku-iku
Route::resource('/iku', \App\Http\Controllers\ikucontroller::class);

I also run php artisan serve.
I've been searching for the solution on the internet but unfortunately, I didn't find anything yet.

run command with specific port php artisan serve --port=9002 . Also run command for config cache php artisan config:cache. And update your .env app_url to APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:9002

if i run "php artisan serve ==port=9002" it shows "Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:9002 (reason: Address already in use)"

Is it possible you are running another Laravel-install already, on port 9002?

@geertjanknapen I'm using Project Idx, how to tell if there is another laravel on port 9002?
